# System.OutOfMemoryException - Windows service stops automatically

Tags: c#, memory, memory-leaks

I have written a windows service, which processes records from the database and updates certain line of businesses

Application developed using C# .NET

I am getting below which is captured in the event viewer

**Application Error:**

```
Faulting application name: MyService.WindowsService.exe, version: 1.0.19092.2, time stamp: 0x5ca328e2
Faulting module name: clrjit.dll, version: 4.7.3260.0, time stamp: 0x5bb7bb2d
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x00004a00
Faulting process id: 0x1c8c
Faulting application start time: 0x01d4ee42fa584c7d
Faulting application path: C:\MyService\WindowsService\1.0.19092.2_1\WindowsService.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clrjit.dll
Report Id: a4f89c01-ef37-41f5-abdf-d2c8c43d72d1
Faulting package full name:
```

**.Net Runtime:**

```
Application: MyService.WindowsService.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.OutOfMemoryException
   at System.Threading.Monitor.ObjPulseAll(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.Monitor.PulseAll(System.Object)
   at Serilog.Sinks.PeriodicBatching.PortableTimer+<OnTick>d__8.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__6_1(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()
```

**Application Error:**

```
Faulting application name: MyService.WindowsService.exe, version: 1.0.19092.2, time stamp: 0x5ca328e2
Faulting module name: clrjit.dll, version: 4.7.3260.0, time stamp: 0x5bb7bb2d
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x00004a00
Faulting process id: 0x15e8
Faulting application start time: 0x01d4edcca1fc92f8
Faulting application path: C:\Service\WindowsService\1.0.19092.2_1\MyService.WindowsService.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clrjit.dll
Report Id: b4f4f164-bdbd-4ed8-a076-b27fbda45927
Faulting package full name:
```

**.Net Runtime:**

```
Application: MyService.WindowsService.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.AccessViolationException
```

How do I trace it?

Comment: Please review this thread as it will give you some suggestions for above error. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/1811e722-8153-4ee6-9979-abc867061b12/quotout-of-memory-exceptionquot-any-suggestions-?forum=clr

Comment: Try to implement IDisposable as much as possible and dispose ununsed objects either in a using() statement or by setting them to null and calling GC.Collect() in a hope that GC will collect them away. Also, sometimes datatypes we use need to be double checked. Do you really need a float where all you need is an unsigned int for example?

Comment: We would need to see how you're processing the data and how you're reading from the database. There are lots of potential causes for the errors listed.